# Moto G Camera resets when app kept in background

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-camera

I was doing android camera video capture through app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionVideoCapture);
```

I am using just intent to launch camera.

My question is: When I click stop video recording and keep app in background, save cancel screen goes away and moto G camera in reset state.

**This is not happening in Nexus 5**

Whats the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: this is basics. not relate to question.

Comment: It's a little unclear as to what you are asking, however, the Moto G has limited memory, and tends to rather aggressively stop background apps. You should ensure that your app successfully maintains state when it is restarted.